# error when meteor run iOS

Tags: meteor

i also meet this problem when meteor run iOS,the error like this,can you give me some advice?

the error is in the attached picture.

[image: meteor run ios error picture]

Answer (score 0):

You could try first to delete the `.meteor/local/cordova-build/` folder.

Meteor will re-build it entirely when you launch the `meteor run ios` command.

This troubleshooting step resolves such issues most of the time.

Comment: when i delete the whole files of cordova-build and rerun iOS again it reports many errors，can see in the attached pic.

Comment: DC74F435-7AF3-4D27-9C44-FBF0514DFFFD.png

Comment: => Errors executing Cordova commands:         
                                              
   While adding platform Android to Cordova project:
   Cordova error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
   at Object.cdProjectRoot
   (/Users/wanghongmei/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.4_4.rwnnka++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/util.js:127:15)
   at Object.platform
(/Users/wanghongmei/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.4_4.rwnnka++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/

Comment: when i create another project and meteor add platform ios then meteor run ios it can run the simulator,it succeeds.But i want to add platform android and ios in one project,and in the project which i add android platform and ios platform it can only run the android emulator but when run ios simulator it will throw the errors i posted in the first question.

Comment: how to add android and ios platform in one project successfully?

Comment: And another problem about the project which added android and ios platform is that when meteor run android it throws one error: E chromium: [ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(340)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:F8A29449DE7F0000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command

Comment: It seems like it's about the buffer_manager,where to set the buffer?

Comment: i add android and ios platform in one new project and it can run successfully all the two emulators,but now still only have the one android error:                                                                                               I20160721-11:47:51.176(8)? 07-21 11:47:50.287 21791 21827 E chromium: [ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(340)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:F8C42F4C237F0000]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command